# C#/Msql automatically calculate the rental payment everyday

Tags: c#, mysql

Hi I have trouble in automatically  calculate the payment/ bill in my Rental Billing system. I would like it to be automatically add the given Rental fee by itself everyday or every 12:00 AM relying on my database date time. 
please do help me :(

Comment: Could you add some code to the question?

Comment: You would benefit from reading [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can build a [service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) and using a [timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) make any kind of computation periodically. Also you can achieve the same result using MySQL routines only, but it's not a good practice in your case, if you have a business logic layer.